# Getting rid of leftover div tag space after negative margin

Tags: css, html, margin

Very simple this, but Im not figuring it out, so please help me.

I have a small div tag `width:50px; height:50px;` positioned inside another div tag `width:600px; height:50px;` The small div tag has a `left:-50px;` because I want it to hang on the side of the bigger div tag (as a tag), and that's working fine, but the bigger div tag still has a *50px* leftover space where the small div tag was before `left:-50px;`

Any ideas on how to get rid of that space? Because I'm going to have a heading in the bigger div tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use absolute position on small div and relative on large in css

big

```
position: relative
```

small

```
position: absolute
```

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to mention they are both inside a container div together with a content div. I applied position: absolute; to the small div and changed from left:-50px; to margin-left:-50px; and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

[CHECK THE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FrxSB/)

Is that what you need?
Parent div should be have `position: relative;` - that will tell the browser to render absolute positioned element relatively to it's parent.